# Array.Copy Confusion

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having the most confusing and annoying problem with Array.Copy.

Heres my code, I know its a bit ugly at the moment I'm just trying to get it to work

```
Char[] Box3Array = new Char[Box1Array.Count() + Ch.Count()];
Array.Copy(Box1Array, Box3Array, Index - 1);
MessageBox.Show("Index = " + Index);
Array.Copy(Ch, 0, Box3Array, Index, Ch.Count());

//Array.Copy(Box1Array, Index, Box3Array, Index + Ch.Count(),     Box3Array.Count() - Ch.Count() - Index);

Box3.Text = new string(Box3Array);
```

Don't worry about the line that is Commented out.

My problem is the second Array.Copy. Index does not seem to work, let me explain. If Index equals 130 then the copy fails and the Ch array is not added. If I actualy type in 130 instead of Index it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? It works if I type an actual number into this line but fails whenever I use Index even if it equals the number I have just experimented with. This is very confusing.

Thanks for any help
Danny

Comment: did you print out the value of Index?

Comment: Yes that is what the MessageBox is there for Anthony

Comment: can you post a screenshot when it fails? does it produce an error?

Comment: so what does the second copy do?

Comment: No MatchesMalone it doesn't produce an error it just doesn't add the second array. Box3.Text displays only the product of the first Array.Copy.

Comment: pm100. I am basicly trying to insert an array of characters into an existing array. This may not be the best way to do this, but this problem has me hooked

Comment: Your Index-1 (129) specify length not location. On your second copy you starts at index (130). So in 3rd array, there are 129 chars then null then the value of ch array.  new string stops at the first null.  Print the Box3Array.count() and loop through the array to see what the value are.

Comment: Whelps, looping through also stops at null.  Use the debugger and put Box3Array in watch window.

Comment: Jules you are right. Subtracted one now it works as it should. I have been programming for almost 30 years and its always the easy things that seem to throw me. Thank you very much. Can't seem to plus one you. If someone else can give Jules a plus one please do.